# How to implement Async Task to fetch data from database using async and await?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

I am doing this. It's working but is this a recommended way to do this. Please comments

```
public async void LoadData()
{
    DataTable  dtAdditionsDetails = await LoadReportData(importID,
                                             InkeyCommon.ToInt32(cmbSellers.SelectedValue),
                                             fromDate,
                                             toDate);
    if (dtAdditionsDetails != null)
      dtaGrdAdditions.ItemSource = dtAdditionsDetails.DefaultView;
} 

public async Task<DataTable> LoadReportData(int? importID,
                                        int sellerID,
                                        DateTime? fromDate,
                                        DateTime? toDate)
{
    DataTable dtAdditionsDetails = new DataTable();

    //Get Report Data                                             
    await Task.Delay(1);

    dtAdditionsDetails = ReportsData.GetRptAdditions(importID,
                                  sellerID,
                                  fromDate,
                                  toDate);

    return dtAdditionsDetails;
}
```

Comment: Why are you implementing an async/await pattern if the actual method that fetches data (GetRptAdditions) is actually synchronous? This doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use the `await` keyword properly, the object being 'awaited' should really be an `...Async` method, like the `GetStringAsync` method. As @ken2k has correctly pointed out, you cannot just `await` any method. Therefore, to answer your question *is this a recommended way to do this?*, the answer is no.

You can find out how to use the `await` and `async` keywords correctly in the [Asynchronous Programming with Async and Await (C# and Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh191443.aspx) page on MSDN, however, if you're just trying to run a synchronous method asynchronously, then you can do that like this:

```
public DataTable LoadData()
{
    DataTable dtAdditionsDetails = ...
    // Get your data here synchronously
    return dtAdditionsDetails;
} 

public async Task<DataTable> LoadDataAsync()
{
    DataTable dtAdditionsDetails = LoadData();
    return Task.Run(() => LoadData());
}
```

...

```
public async void GetDataAsynchronously()
{
    DataTable dtAdditionsDetails = await LoadDataAsync();
}
```

Note that `...Async` methods (usually) return `Task<T>` objects, rather than nothing and that their names end in the word `Async`. Also note that only the data is returned from `...Async` methods and *not* the `Task<T>` and that we *don't* `await` when there is nothing to `await`.

Comment: I am using await Task.Delay(1). Is this a correct way to implement this?

Comment: `Task.Delay` has nothing to do with this, so no, that is not appropriate to use here.

Comment: I tried to use this code, but it seems not be valid...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple function, to load a list of all `[User]` records from a database, using `async` and `await`.

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
{
    try
    {
        //  Fetch a list of all the [User] records, just for the hell of it.
        var users = await Task.Run(() => dbContextWebMgt.Users.ToList());
        return new OkObjectResult(users);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return new BadRequestObjectResult(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this using NPoco ORM

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAsync()

{
      IList myList = await FetchAsync();
}
```